# Synergy + EA Origin, client-connected PC can no longer click

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, synergy

On hosting PC, Win 8, Synergy ver 1.8.7-stable-9799e96 (same version on client-connected PC Win7), if I have Electronic Arts Origin desktop app (ver 10.4.6.29454 - 0) signed-in and running, left and right-clicking on the client-connected PC no longer functions. No game running, just the app.

Closing Origin, or even just leaving Origin at its sign-in screen, allows clicking function to work normally again. Host PC is fine either way. Client PC can click normally during this situation with its own mouse connected.

Might there any workaround that I could try to do?

Comment: Ah, just realized though, curiously, with the dev version of Origin connecting from Win7 to Win7, I don't have this issue. So Origin still seems to be the core issue, but perhaps there's something in Win 8 as well that's also causing an issue while it's open?

Comment: I've had the same issue here, but instead of Origin, VMware Workstation (and only in full screen mode) seems to be the culprit on my end.